# Why is operator<< for enum not being used?

Tags: c++, enums

In the following code, can someone please explain why if the code delimited by "ifdef TEST" is enabled, the operator<< function I have defined to print an enumeration as string doesn't get used.  It seems to me that the code that's causing my problem should be unrelated to the printing of the enum in class Container especially since the problem code references a different class (Container2).

If I build with g++ filename.cpp, the output is:

```
Print for Container: mycolor is red
```

If I build with g++ -DTEST filename.cpp, the output is:

```
Print for Container: mycolor is 0
```

Code follows:
    #include

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    enum color {red, blue};
}
namespace mynamespace
{
    class Container
    {
    public:
        mynamespace::color mycolor1;
        explicit Container() : mycolor1(mynamespace::red) {};
        std::ostream &Print(std::ostream& os) const;
    };
    class Container2
    {
    };
}
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const mynamespace::color &_color);

namespace mynamespace
{
#ifdef TEST
// If this is defined, the printing of the enum in Container does not use the operator<< function to output the enum as a string
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Container2 &i);
#endif
}

int main()
{
    // Create a Container.  Default color is red
    mynamespace::Container *container = new mynamespace::Container;
    container->Print(std::cout);
}

std::ostream & mynamespace::Container::Print(std::ostream &os) const
{
    os << "Print for Container: mycolor is " << mycolor1 << std::endl;
    return os;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const mynamespace::color &_color)
{
    switch(_color)
    {
        case mynamespace::red: os << "red"; break;
        case mynamespace::blue: os << "blue"; break;
        default: os << "unknown"; break;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplified example:

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    enum color {red, blue};

    class Container
    {
    public:
        mynamespace::color mycolor1;
        explicit Container() : mycolor1(mynamespace::red) {};
        std::ostream &Print(std::ostream& os) const;
    };
    class Container2
    {
    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Container2 &i);
}
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const mynamespace::color &_color);

std::ostream & mynamespace::Container::Print(std::ostream &os) const
{
    os << mycolor1 << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

The expression `os << mycolor1` looks for a function named `operator<<`. The function will be searched for as a member function of `std::ostream` and (independently, additionally) via unqualified lookup, triggering ADL.

The unqualified lookup via ADL will find `mynamespace::operator<<`.
The "pure" unqualified lookup (no ADL) will start from the scope of the function body of `Print`, which is the scope of the class `Container` (*) and traverse the surrounding scopes *until a function named `operator<<` is found*. Then it *stops*. Here, it stops at `mynamespace` as well: This is the first surrounding scope that has a function with that name. The global namespace *is not searched*.

You can make "pure" unqualified lookup find the global function e.g. by saying:

```
std::ostream & mynamespace::Container::Print(std::ostream &os) const
{
    using ::operator<<;
    os << mycolor1 << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

---

(*) You can think of it as

```
namespace mynamespace { enum color {red, blue}; class Container2; }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const mynamespace::color &_color);

namespace mynamespace
{
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Container2 &i);

    class Container
    {
    public:
        mynamespace::color mycolor1;
        explicit Container() : mycolor1(mynamespace::red) {};

        std::ostream &Print(std::ostream& os) const
        {
            os << mycolor1 << std::endl;
            return os;
        }
    };
};
```

Here, it might be clearer that the first surrounding scope of `os << mycolor1` that contains a function named `operator<<` is `mynamespace`.

---

IMHO, a good solution would be to put the `operator<<` for the enum in `mynamespace` as well:

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    enum color {red, blue};
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const mynamespace::color &_color);
}
```

This way, it can be found via ADL.

Answer (score 1):

your problem as mentioned in the comment is that the namespace function is hiding all the global functions with the same name;
the easiest solution is to put a `using` statement in the fwd declaration, like this:

```
namespace mynamespace
{
  using ::operator<<;
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Container2 &i);
}
```

This tell the compiler that you are not replacing the global scope function, you are just overloading it.